# Addressing multiple inputs in shiny

Tags: r, regex, shiny

I am building a relatively complicated app, where I have dynamic number of inputs titled:
d1, d2 .. dn. At one point I wanted to try addressing multiple inputs at the same time with:

```
input[[grep(pattern="d+[[:digit:]]",input)]]
```

which of course caused an error:

```
Must use single string to index into reactivevalues
```

So I was wondering whether someone knew an elegant way to do such a thing?

Comment: related: [using-a-list-of-input-names-into-observeevent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73352553/r-shiny-using-a-list-of-input-names-into-observeevent/73352718#73352718)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use names on input :

```
grep(pattern = "d+[[:digit:]]", x = names(input), value = TRUE)
```

A working example :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      lapply(
        X = 1:6,
        FUN = function(i) {
          sliderInput(inputId = paste0("d", i), label = i, min = 0, max = 10, value = i)
        }
      )
    ),
    column(
      width = 6,
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "test")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output){
  output$test <- renderPrint({
    sapply(grep(pattern = "d+[[:digit:]]", x = names(input), value = TRUE), function(x) input[[x]])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the actual values behind the names?

Comment: Yes, check the example

Comment: Just one question - how could I address multiple inputs in observeEvent?

Comment: I am currently stuck with observeEvent(c(input$d1,input$d2,input$d3),{})

Comment: You can use : `observeEvent(lapply(grep(pattern = "d+[[:digit:]]", x = names(input), value = TRUE), function(x) input[[x]]), {})`