# Get the event which is fired in Shiny?

Tags: r, events, shiny

I would like to know in the example below which event is fired in  the multiple `ObserveEvent()`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("a", "a", 0),
  textInput("b", "b")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent({
    input$a
    input$b
  },{

    # If only input$a is fired, I want to know that is input$a

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Or the only solution is to have two `ObserveEvent()` like the second link ? like that ?

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("a", "a", 0),
  textInput("b", "b")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent({
    input$a
  },{

    my_function_or_reactive_function(input,1)

  })

  observeEvent({
    input$b
  },{

    my_function_or_reactive_function(input,2)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

link:

- [How to listen for more than one event expression within a Shiny eventReactive handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34731975/how-to-listen-for-more-than-one-event-expression-within-a-shiny-eventreactive-ha/34752260#34752260)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/vd_nB-BH8sw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use shiny's [JS event](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html) `shiny:inputchanged` to check which input changed:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
          if (event.name != 'changed') {
            Shiny.setInputValue('changed', event.name);
          }
        });"
    )
  ),
  numericInput("a", "a", 0),
  textInput("b", "b"),
  textInput("c", "c"),
  textOutput("changedInputs"),
  textOutput("aFired")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$changedInputs <- renderText({
    paste("Outside observer: Latest input fired:", paste(input$changed, collapse = ", "))
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    c(input$a,
      input$b)
  }, {
    req(input$changed)
    if (input$changed == "a") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$a was fired")
    } else if (input$changed == "b") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$b was fired")
    } else if (input$changed == "c") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$c was fired")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

[image: Result]:

**Edit** - request from @TristanTran using `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      "$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
          if (event.name != 'changed') {
            Shiny.setInputValue('changed', event.name);
          }
        });"
    )
  ),
  uiOutput("serverside"),
  textOutput("changedInputs"),
  textOutput("aFired")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$changedInputs <- renderText({
    paste("Outside observer: Latest input fired:", paste(input$changed, collapse = ", "))
  })
  
  output$serverside <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      numericInput("a", "a", 0),
      textInput("b", "b"),
      textInput("c", "c")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent({
    c(input$a,
      input$b)
  }, {
    req(input$changed)
    if (input$changed == "a") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$a was fired")
    } else if (input$changed == "b") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$b was fired")
    } else if (input$changed == "c") {
      output$aFired <- renderText("Inside observer: input$c was fired")
    }
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much: ) I'm surprised that this functionality doesn't exist by default in `observeEvent()`.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, it would definitely make a nice convenience feature. You could propose it [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues). Maybe they are interested.

Comment: I have a problem. If I add `textInput("c", "c")`, when I trigger `c` then `observeEvent(c(input$a,input$b),` catches  `.clientdata_output_changedInputs_hidden` and `c` also.

Comment: and without `Shiny.setInputValue()` `observeEvent(c(input$a,input$b),` catches only `a` and `b`.

Comment: Currently the JS code catches all changed inputs, thats why I used `if (input$changed == "a")` inside the observer to react only when `input$a` was changed. You could also adapt the JS code to only listen on changes of `input$a` by using `event.name == 'a'` but that's less flexible.

Comment: Just updated my answer to show it more clearly. The observer only reacts to `a` and `b`. You were probably looking at the text output which is rendered outside the observer.

Comment: no no. I don't agree with your 13:23 answer. :) I will not use  `Shiny.setInputValue()` in this case. But in your initial answer it works but `renderText()` return  "outside the observer"(13:41). In fact it is in my real app that I have reactive consequences with [Addressing multiple inputs in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044768/addressing-multiple-inputs-in-shiny/40045292#40045292) and maybe `Shiny.setInputValue()`. Could you remove your last answer and put your initial answer, please :)

Comment: Added a gif to show that when adding `input$c` it is not interfering with the `observeEvent(c(input$a,input$b)`.

Comment: ha :) I was doing the same in your code because you initial render outside observer was confusing. Thank you :)

Comment: My new question :) with `grep()` and `setInputValue()`. [Get the event which is fired in Shiny and with grep (generated input)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776207/get-the-event-which-is-fired-in-shiny-and-with-grep-generated-input)

Comment: @ismirsehregal This works on the usual input elements standing alone (such as ```textInput```, ```numericInput```). How do I modify this to work for these same elements embedded in an ```uiOutput``` element which embeds many of such individual input elements? In such a case, ```input$changed``` does not produce the name of the fired input, but the name of the ```uiOutput``` element and the action on that element, like this ```sample_table_cell_click```, where ```sample_table``` is my ```uiOutput``` element.

Comment: @TristanTran please see my edit. It's working fine also with `renderUI`. However, if you still have problems with your special case, try to create a simple example and post it as a new question.