# Take action when any of the button is clicked Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, action-button

How to observe when any of the multiple buttons is clicked? For example, we have three buttons, I would like to show the notification when any of the buttons is clicked. Here is an example code

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('button1', 'button1'),actionButton('button2', 'button2'),actionButton('button3', 'button3'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  
  
  observe({
    
    req(input$button1, input$button2, input$button3)
    
    
    showNotification("This is a notification.")
    
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The above code is not satisfactory because when initiate the page, only when three buttons are all clicked, notification shows.

Also, is it possible to know which button is cliecked?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at [Get the event which is fired in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56771353/10489562).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `observeEvent` instead and put all your triggers in `c()`

```r
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton('button1', 'button1'),actionButton('button2', 'button2'),actionButton('button3', 'button3'))
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(c(input$button1, input$button2, input$button3), ignoreInit = TRUE, {
        showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert **input** to a list and use it as your trigger object for an observeEvent:

```
observeEvent(reactiveValuesToList(input),{
  #do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Some alternative ways of doing this:

```
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('button1', 'button1'), 
  actionButton('button2', 'button2'), 
  actionButton('button3', 'button3'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  paste0('button', 1:3) %>% 
  map(~ observeEvent(input[[.x]], {
    showNotification("This is the general notification.")
    showNotification(paste(.x, 'pressed'))
  }))
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

or using only `observe()`:

```
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('button1', 'button1'),actionButton('button2', 'button2'),actionButton('button3', 'button3'))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    nms <- str_subset(names(input), 'button')
    if ( any(map_lgl(nms,~ input[[.x]] != 0)) ) {
      
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
      
    } 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```